# Workbench: Bulk CSV - where do I access the data

Tags: migration, workbench

I have submitted a sql query in Workbench and the status indicates the job is complete with 470249 records - o records failed.  My question is where do I pick up the file when I click the ID link I only get my SQL statement back. I am assuming it is on a server somewhere .... but where. It is not in my download file nor desktop nor on C.  Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Comment: If you see a blue color icon that says download complete batch results before the ID click on it, and not on the Id.

Answer (score 7):

See image for the link to download the CSV. GRRRRRRRRRRRRR not letting me post without 30 characters SFSE :X
[image]

Comment: rao, I'd just like to say... this is a hilarious answer. Accurate, of course, but hilarious.

Comment: lols sfdcfox humor paid me 20 points, so cant complaint :)

Comment: When I was trying, It took some time to appear that small download icon.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting same problem but i just resolve it with following these steps,
Just go through Setup--> Jobs--> Bulk Data Load Jobs. 
Now you can see all error records with error msgs along with success records.